# Redial Last Incoming Call without Unlocking Phone

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-lock

I left my iPhone X running iOS 11 at a casino. Someone at the casino called two of my contacts while they had my phone.

- 1:32 Brian calls my phone to see if we can hear it
- 6:36 My phone calls Brian
- 9:32 Nancy calls my phone to see if we can hear it
- 10:52 My phone calls Nancy

Between 9:32 and 10:52 I miraculously remembered my iCloud password, so we already knew where the phone was and we were on our way there.

But I haven't been able to figure out how they made those calls. I assume it has something to do with them being at the top of the Recent Calls list.

I'm pretty sure (but not 100%) that I had Siri disabled. If I did have it enabled, I would have also had it enabled on the lock screen. But even in that state, I can only get it to show me the last caller and it tells me I have to unlock to make the call.

Is it possible to redial the last incoming call without unlocking?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Under **Settings > Notifications**, if you have **"Show Previews" > Always** along with  **Phone > Alerts > Show on Lock Screen**, then all you have to do is tap on the missed call from the lock screen to call it back.

Comment: I have Show Previews. When unlocked. And it was definitely set that way at the time

Comment: @DickKusleika There’s an additional “show previews” option within the **Notifications > Phone > Show Previews > Always** that is enabled by default.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about that. At the very bottom, under OPTIONS, mine says `Show Previews  When Unlocked (Default)`. I don't know if that was the default back then.

Comment: @DickKusleika Yes, that's the option I'm referring to. It's enabled by default.