# Redial last number

Tags: iphone, phone.app

Is there a way to quickly redial the last number in the phone.app? I know you can go into recents but is there a quicker way on iOS 12 using iPhone SE?

Comment: Never tried this but what if you say, "Siri, redial last number?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D press your phone application and go to “ view most recent calls “
Then select the number you want to dial.

Go to phone.app and go to the keypad screen.
Then with no numbers pressed, press the green dial icon. This will automatically show the last dialled number.

Comment: my phone doesn't have 3d touch, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. Go to phone.app and go to the keypad screen.

Then with no numbers pressed, press the green dial icon. This will automatically show the last dialled number.

This is also possible if you received the calls while locked.

From [Redial Last Incoming Call without Unlocking Phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320050/redial-last-incoming-call-without-unlocking-phone):

> Under Settings > Notifications, if you have "Show Previews" > Always along with Phone > Alerts > Show on Lock Screen, then all you have to do is tap on the missed call from the lock screen to call it back.